# convert yyyy-dd-mm to yyyy-mm-dd in python

Tags: python, pandas

Please advice how to convert following using python
from:

```
2010-01-04 00:00:00
```

to:

```
2010-04-01 00:00:00
```

I have tried

```
df.Month = pd.to_datetime(df.Month, format('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

but didn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the data present? Is it a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes sir its a dataframe in pandas

Comment: Where on earth is yyyy-dd-mm used? I thought yyyy-mm-dd was the one unambiguous format there was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.dt.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2010-01-04 00:00:00"]})
print( pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%d-%m") )
```

**Output:**

```
0    2010-04-01
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following using datetime parser and returning it in a defined format:

```
from datetime import datetime
old_date_string='2010-01-04 00:00:00'
dt=datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
new_date_string=dt.strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
```

However, when you want to work with the date I would suggest using the datetime object